# UITable view selection stay highlighted

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am using XCode4.2 to develop a storyboard application

I am switching views based on a click in a UITableView after clicking the row is highlighted in blue and the new view is loaded .

when I come back to the original view the row is still highlighted in blue ... how can I disable that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

That way I have the index path that was selected every time.

Comment: There I fixed capitolization, if that doesn't work, then the class you're putting this code in isn't a delegate for the table view...

Answer (score 1):

use `deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated` function to deselect rows in uitableview

call it in your viewWillAppear function

`[yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:NO];`

if you are not sure which is index you select last time you can run a loop on all the index path in your table.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for(int i = 0; i <= [yourArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }

}
```

Note: As I don't know your exact code....you need to modify above code to your needs.

Comment: I can t find this function , I am in a UIView controller and I have a table inside it ... is it the same as -(void)tableView:(UITableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

also what should I write in the body of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

A UITableViewController does this automatically. Otherwise, in your `viewDidAppear` for the owning controller, you need to call `- (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated` on the table view.

Comment: I can t find this function , I am in a UIView controller and I have a table inside it ... is it the same as -(void)tableView:(UITableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

also what should I write in the body of the function ?

Comment: `deselectRowAtIndexPath` is a member of `UITableView`.

Comment: You don't write it. You call it from `viewDidAppear` in your controller.